# MITM risk of not sanitizing?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, sanitization

The plugin review team has rejected my plugin because they say I'm not sanitizing data. Here is the snippet:

```
function add_cookie_to_order( $order_id ) {
    if ( isset( $_COOKIE['tm_clickid'] ) && preg_match( '/^[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]?[0-9a-f]{32}$/', $_COOKIE['tm_clickid'] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $order_id, 'tm_clickid', $_COOKIE['tm_clickid'] );
    }
}
```

I pointed out that the `preg_match` is very strict and allows only 2 or 3 uppercase chars + 32 hex chars, but they answered:

> > as you can see, we do the sanitizing with the preg_match on line 54 (previously line 52).
>
> Except you're not. You're validating there, but
> with the gap between the check and the save, you leave yourself open
> to a MITM attack. Which is why you always sanitize when you save. That
> is why we said this:
>
> > You still have to sanitize, as a well timed MITM attack will obviate your check.

I really don't understand where "the gap between the check and the save" is, and how could a MITM happen...

Would this be ok? (I don't see any increased security in this, only useless overhead):

```
if ( isset( $_COOKIE['tm_clickid'] ) && preg_match( '/^[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]?[0-9a-f]{32}$/', $_COOKIE['tm_clickid'] ) ) {
    $tm_clickid = sanitize_text_field( $_COOKIE['tm_clickid'] );
    update_post_meta( $order_id, 'tm_clickid', $tm_clickid );
}
```

Comment: No, that doesn't make any sense to me either, especially the bit about the MITM attack - MITM where exactly? Unless they're talking about a different check and save?

Comment: Would that be OK? You'll have to ask them. And ask if they can be specific about which attack and save they mean and where the gap is, and / or suggest how to fix it please, if that's not correct.

Comment: (At a pinch they could be talking about some filter in update_post_meta, where someone malicious with the ability to install a plugin could change the value before it's written to the database, but that's silly to have to worry about that, and that's not "well timed".)

Comment: But that is completely stupid. Someone would have to inject code into your system to exploit that, and if they can do that there's worse things to worry about that sanitizing a value you read from a cookie. Oh well, whatever keeps them happy.

Comment: Apparently that would be ok for them... ‍♂️

Comment: On second thought I suppose it's an extra line of defence in case there's ever an exploitable bug in preg_match. But that's a very large 'if'. As long as the default santize implementation doesn't use regexes that is. But hey.

Comment: maybe they have some internal code checker that doesn't understand that variable is "safe" unless it goes through one of their function

Comment: and it doesn't allow them to approve the plugin in that case

Comment: Yeah, that would make sense. But if I was them I'd say exactly that - we require that all external input explicitly go through sanitize, no matter how sure you are that it is safe - rather than making up nonsense about MITMs.

Answer (score 1):

This is the official answer from the WordPress Plugin Review Team:

> PHP runs processes one at a time.
>
> If step 1 is "Validate" and step 2 is save, then between step 1 and 2
> is where a MITM happens.
>
> Now. You may be thinking "But come on, nothing could possibly happen
> there! That's too fast!" And the probability is you are 99% correct.
> But. is that 1% worth the risk? No. Not when you can just wrap it and
> sanitize it and save yourself from a hacker more clever than you or I.
>
> Remember a lot of santization is 'Are you SURE?' and really we never
> are.
>
> This is fine:
>
> function add_cookie_to_order( $order_id ) { if ( isset(
> $_COOKIE['tm_clickid'] ) && preg_match(
> '/^[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]?[0-9a-f]{32}$/', $_COOKIE['tm_clickid'] ) ) {
> $tm_clickid = sanitize_text_field( $_COOKIE['tm_clickid'] );
> update_post_meta( $order_id, 'tm_clickid', $tm_clickid ); } }

So you have to do it that way and pass the variable through the wordpress sanitize function, to have the plugin approved.